# Subscript out of range Run time error'9' in macro used to copy from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am completely new to writing macros and just getting to know how it works. I need to copy data from one workbook onto another one, this is the macro that i came up with:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyMainTable()
    Dim SourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim DestWorkbook As Workbook
    
    ' Set references to the source and destination workbooks
    Set SourceWorkbook = Workbooks("Monthly Report.xlsx")
    Set DestWorkbook = Workbooks("ANNUAL REPORT.xlsx")
    
    ' Copy data from source to destination
    SourceWorkbook.Sheets("SITE1").Range("B19:Av43").Copy Destination:=DestWorkbook.Sheets("SITE1").Range("B19")
    
    Set SourceWorkbook = Nothing
    Set DestWorkbook = Nothing

    
End Sub
```

Problem is that when it runs it comes up with a run-time error 9: subscript out of range, i checked the cells on both workbooks and they do match one to one

I made sure al names were correctly spelled, and checked the cells on the worksheets

Comment: Are the workbooks open?  Have you double checked (as in copy pasted) the Workbook names and suffix, as well as the sheet name?

Comment: Maybe your actual folder is not the same as where the files are. Define fully qualified pathname for the two sources. `"C:\Users\...\...\Monthly Report.xlsx"`

Comment: I remember i did open it in code using the workbook.open statement, and it tells me that the file does not exist, i have checked the spelling as i mentioned in the question but i am unsure how file paths have to fe refferenced if they are on the same folder, i am trying to use relative paths since these workbooks have to be moved in between different machines but i can count all of the workbooks that need to be compiled are in the same folder

Comment: I am deliberately trying to avoid using absolute paths so the folder and the workbooks my book compiles can be moved in between different machines and interchanged, since i just started learning yesterday i am not sure if an absolute path would make it not be movable, but it it won't affect then i am game for doing that

Comment: Other weird thing i found, is that whenever i open the workbook it has the table filled with the correct information from the other workbook despite crashing when i run trough it

Comment: Where is the code located, in another workbook ? If so are all 3 workbooks in the same folder ?

Comment: 12 workbooks that need to be compiled, this macro is stored in the yearly report, which is the one i am working in, so 13 in total in the folder

Comment: What is the filename of the yearly report?

Comment: same as in the code "YEARLY REPORT.xlsx", I was looking at the documentation earlier, i think better to refference it as ThisWorkbook

Comment: The code has `ANNUAL REPORT.xlsx` but that is xlsX. Macro workbooks are usually xlsM

Comment: i did change it, but still, it should work now that i refference it as ThisWorkbook

Comment: Try `Set SourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Monthly Report.xlsx")`

Comment: I have been checking other questions as well as the documentation, using this way of refferencing it now comes with an error of '91': Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: There it works now, Thank you so much to all of you who answered, now as a bonus, i would need to know if this file exists within the same folder before trying to open it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyMainTable()

    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim rngCopy As Range
    Dim sFolder As String, sourceFile As String, s As String
   
    ' Set references to the source and destination workbooks
    Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
    sFolder = wbDest.Path & "\"
    sourceFile = "Monthly Report.xlsx"
    
    ' check source file exists then open
    s = sFolder & sourceFile
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(s, ReadOnly:=True)
    If wbSource Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox sourceFile & " not found in " & sFolder, vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' check sheet
        Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("SITE1")
        If wsSource Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Sheet SITE1 not found in " & wbSource.Name, vbCritical
            wbSource.Close
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Copy data from source to destination
    Set rngCopy = wsSource.Range("B19:AA43")
    rngCopy.Copy Destination:=wbDest.Sheets("SITE1").Range("B19")
    
    MsgBox rngCopy.Address & " copied from " & wbSource.Name, vbInformation
    wbSource.Close

End Sub
```